# Javascript calculation is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview

I have a `gridview` in which there is a row in which I add integer values like `7000`.

So if there are 2-3 rows added, I want to add all those rows values and show it in the `textbox`

So for that, I have written the below code

```
if (document.getElementById('txtTotalExp').value == "") {
            var Expense = 0;
        } else {
            var Expense = document.getElementById('txtTotalExp').value;
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < GridExpInfo.Rows.length; i++) {
            var totAmount = GridExpInfo.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value;
            var totval = totAmount;
            Expense += parseInt(totval);
        }
```

`document.getElementById('txtTotalLandVal').value = parseInt(TotalPayableValue) + parseInt(Expense);`

But In the textbox it is coming something like this
 **200010001512**

The addition operation is not working.

Comment: instead of document.getElementById('txtTotalExp').value; use parseInt(document.getElementById('txtTotalExp').value,10) and make sure you use parseInt(value,10) 10 as radix to make calculation in base 10 for some special value it converts to hexadecimal

Comment: Please create [mcve] so that we can see what might be wrong. There is no way we can verify what is happening with only that javascript.

Comment: PascalCase should be used only in Constructors, avoid using it on any other kind of type.

Comment: @VinodLouis: let me try and check this

Comment: @VinodLouis: Getting error as `Microsoft JScript runtime error: Cannot assign to a function result` at this line `parseInt(document.getElementById('txtTotalLandVal').value) = parseInt(TotalPayableValue) + parseInt(Expense);`

Comment: @nad Im not saying at this line do at this line  var Expense = document.getElementById('txtTotalExp').value; and for use parseInt(value,10) everywhere just to be on safe side

Answer (score 1):

I interpret your question to mean that you have a table with rows of values, you want to sum each row, and then you want to get a total sum-of-the-row-sums for the entire table.

I wanted to provide a working code snippet to demonstrate a solution to your problem. However, because you didn't provide all the necessary code, I invented some of it. In the process of doing so, I provided an alternative, and perhaps more modern, approach to solving the overall problem I think you were trying to solve. Yes, it's providing significantly more than what you were asking for (...I think some of the other answers that discuss `parseInt` might solve your initial problem) but hopefully this gives you some further insight.

The example below shows how to do this using many recent features of JavaScript. Hopefully the comments explain what is happening at every step in enough detail that you get a sense of the logic. To understand each step, you are probably going to have dig deeper into learning more JavaScript. A good reference is the [Mozilla Developer Network (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/), which contains documentation on all these features.

```js
// when the button is clicked, do the following...
document.querySelector('button').onclick = () => {

  // calculate the total sum across the table
  const rowSums =

    // get a nodeList of all table rows in the entire document
    // and convert that array-like nodeList to a true array
    // of table row elements
    [...document.querySelectorAll('tr')]

      // remove the first row, i.e. ignore the row of column headers
      .slice(1)

      // from the original array of table rows (minus the first row)
      // create a new array in which each element is derived
      // from the corresponding table row from the original array
      .map(row => {

        // calculate the sum of values across this row
        const rowSum =

          // get a nodeList of all table cells in this row
          // and convert that array-like nodeList to a true array
          // of table cell elements
          [...row.querySelectorAll('td')]

            // remove the last cell, i.e. ignore the cell that will eventually
            // hold the sum for this row
            .slice(0,-1)

            // from the array of table cells for this row (minus the last one)
            // derive a new single value by progressively doing something
            // for each cell
            .reduce(

              // for each table cell in this row, remember the cell itself
              // as well as the accumulating value we are gradually deriving from all
              // the cells in this row, i.e. the sum of all values across this row
              (accumulatingRowSum, cell) =>

                // for each cell in this row, add the numerical value
                // of the current cell to the sum of values we are accumulating
                // across this row
                accumulatingRowSum + parseInt(cell.innerHTML, 10),

              // start our accumulating sum of values across this row with zero
              0
            );

        // get all the cells in this row
        const rowCells = row.querySelectorAll('td');

        // put the sum of values from this row into the last cell of the row
        rowCells[rowCells.length - 1].innerHTML = rowSum;

        // place the sum of values in this row into the accumulating array
        // of all such values for all rows
        return rowSum;
  });
  
  // calculate the total sum for the whole table
  const totalExpenses =

    // start with the array of sums for each row
    rowSums

      // similar to `reduce` above, reduce the array of multiple row sums
      // into a single value of the total sum, calculated by adding together
      // all the individual row sums, starting with zero
      .reduce((accumulatingTotalSum, rowTotal) => accumulatingTotalSum + rowTotal, 0);

  // place the total sum into the appropriate span element
  document.querySelector('#txtTotalExp').innerHTML = totalExpenses;
};
```

```css
table {
  border: solid black 1px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
  border: solid black 1px;
  padding: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><th>col1</th><th>col2</th><th>row total</th></tr>
  <tr><td>3500</td><td>1200</td><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td>2700</td><td>4500</td><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td>3100</td><td>1300</td><td></td></tr>
</table>
<p>The total expenses are: <span id="txtTotalExp"></span></p>
<button>Calculate</button>
```

Comment: thanks Andrew for your answer, but  for now I am able to manage with some other code. IF needed will ping you for some help

Answer (score 0):

you can used below code:

```
var total=parseInt(TotalPayableValue,10) + parseInt(Expense,10);
    document.getElementById('txtTotalLandVal').value=total;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var Expense = 0;
if (document.getElementById('txtTotalExp').value != "") {
 var Expense = parseInt(document.getElementById('txtTotalExp').value);
}
for (var i = 0; i < GridExpInfo.Rows.length; i++) {
 var totAmount = GridExpInfo.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value;
 Expense += parseInt(totAmount);
}
```

The problem: Expense initially can be a string. Have you tried if with "Expense = 0" the error occurs?